# How to display this (2019/10/30 10:30:00) time format in ion-datetime

Tags: datetime, ionic-framework, ionic3

I want to display this time format in ion-datetime. Both date and time I want to display.
But when I am assigning this value to ngmodel it is not displaying.
Can anyone please help me how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use displayForamt attribute to show date like this.
Check Example blow.

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-label>D MMM YYYY H:mm</ion-label>
  <ion-datetime pickerFormat="YYYY/MM/DD H:mm:s" displayFormat="YYYY/MM/DD H:mm:ss" min="1997" max="2010" [(ngModel)]="dateN"></ion-datetime>
</ion-item>
```

Answer (score 0):

set your date in this format `YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm:ss` for example `2019/08/05 09:35:07`

Here is an example in your .ts file `current = '2019/08/01 04:31:07'; // you can format your date to fit this`

then in your html
 `<ion-datetime [(ngModel)]="current" displayFormat="YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm:ss" pickerFormat="YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm:ss"></ion-datetime>`

`displayFormat` decides how you want the date-time to be displayed